# AJAX.ACTIONLINK inside a TR element does NOT do a partial update

Tags: ajax, html-table, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views, actionlink

I have two action links. One inside a table (with one column and one row, just for testing purposes) and a copy of the that link OUTSIDE a table.

Only the link outside the table does an AJAX update.

Here is my view:

```
Dim TaskPanelUpdateOptions As AjaxOptions = New AjaxOptions() 'setup the ajax options. this will target a div for a partial update
With TaskPanelUpdateOptions
    .UpdateTargetId = "taskpanel"
    .InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
End With
%>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%
            Response.Write(Ajax.ActionLink("Show in grid", "ShowDetails", "Workflow", New With {.WorkflowMasterId = CType(Model.WorkflowsList.Rows(0), vantageTEM.Business.WorkflowDataset.OpenWorkflowRow).Wfm_Id}, TaskPanelUpdateOptions, Nothing))
        %>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<%  Response.Write(Ajax.ActionLink("Show not in grid", "ShowDetails", "Workflow", New With {.WorkflowMasterId = CType(Model.WorkflowsList.Rows(0), vantageTEM.Business.WorkflowDataset.OpenWorkflowRow).Wfm_Id}, TaskPanelUpdateOptions, Nothing))
```

When I click The link NOT in the grid it updates the div correctly.

When I click the link IN the grid it seems to render ONLY the partial view?

Any idea why, or how I can overcome this?

Comment: Hi did u find the solution to this. I would appreciate any help. Thx

Comment: likewise - having the same problem